# Flatten nested JSON blob in snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, blob

I'm trying to flatten the following JSON Blob in MyTable which is varchar:

MyTable

| A | B | JSONBlob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | {"a": "12345", "b": "city", "c": "state", "d": {"e":"567", "f":"llc"} } |
| y | 2 | {"a": "6789", "b": "country", "c": "county", "d": {"e":"999", "f":"col"} } |

What I've tried so far that is returning no results:

```
select
f. value as a
, f1.value:f as f
from MyTable
, lateral flatten(input => PARSE_JSON(MyTable.JSONBlob)) f
, lateral flatten(input => f.value:d) f1
```

I'd like to query to get the results in the following format:

| a | f |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | llc |
| 6789 | col |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to flatten if all your data looks like example.

The values in `f` is just nested in `d` in the example above.

This SQL will give you the result you are looking for

```
select jb:a::text a, jb:d:f::text f
  from (select PARSE_JSON(JSONBlob) jb
          from myTable)
```

Tested with the following and the result is below

```
with myTable(A,B,JSONBlob) as (
select * from (values
('x',1,'{"a": "12345", "b": "city", "c": "state", "d": {"e":"567", "f":"llc"} }'),
('y',2,'{"a": "6789", "b": "country", "c": "county", "d": {"e":"999", "f":"col"} }'))
)
select jb:a::text a, jb:d:f::text f
  from (select PARSE_JSON(JSONBlob) jb
          from myTable)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works great except for some of the fields. When using my actual data, a field similar to jb:d:e above is returning null when I do 'select jb:d:e::text' for some reason. What would be the reason for this?

Comment: You are welcome. This happens if  `e` is  missing in `d`.